# Where's the Module Name for Angular Material Components? | NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:

Tags: angular, angular-material

Where do I find the module to import to use [`<mat-chip-list>`](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)?  I'm thinking it would be under the API tab but that is empty.

[image: empty api tab]

---

I'm receiving the following error since I'm not importing the correct module:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
>
> 'mat-chip-list' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-chip-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-chip-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message....

Comment: I opened https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api and see `import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material';`

Comment: There it is.  Must have been some temporary glitch early, thanks!

Comment: I usually watch this path https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app for the examples and all modules can be found here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/demo-material-module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must have been a temporary glitch as it is there now:

[image: api tab]